# PHP5 for Snow Leopard is not working even with the module enabled

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard

This is the guide I followed to make PHP work on Snow Leopard:

http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard

Apache2 is working.
http://localhost.lan works just fine. Virtualhost works too.
Mysql is working.

PHP5 is not even with 
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: If your're not using it as production server try MAMP.

Comment: I am not using it as production server. It's my dev setup. I also use Ruby by the way so I prefer to get this fixed rather than use MAMP.

Answer (score 2):

I think your apache2 install has a problem.
You need to re-install apache2 then try

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

again.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Neoryder's post, edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, find the line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and remove the hash sign from the beginning to enable PHP in your web server. You have to go to your *Sharing* preference pane and uncheck and recheck *Web sharing* for the change to take effect.

I'll mention one more thing that caught me out moving from Linux to OS X...

Most people want to serve PHP files from their own `Sites` folders. There's lots of advice out there about configuring Apache using `.htaccess` files, and some of it won't work under OS X because Apache is locked down a bit by default.

For example, if you want to have PHP files ending with `.html` or `.htm`, most people will tell you to create an `.htaccess` file and put in it the line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

If you're a developer and this is annoying you, you may want to edit the file `/etc/apache2/users/<myusername>.conf` and change the line:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

This will allow your local `.htaccess` files to override various global defaults that they couldn't before.

Comment: I actually knew about AllowOverride All. But the issue was a broken setup of apache2. What worked for me:

These are the guides I followed which worked very well.

http://diymacserver.com/installing-apache/compiling-apache-in-64-bits-mode-on-leopard/

http://diymacserver.com/installing-php/

http://diymacserver.com/installing-apache/starting-apache-at-boot-on-leopard

I also removed the default apache2 which comes with Leopard.

sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2

Install fink before installing PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a late answer...but I had the exact same problem and I used [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install a later version of php:

http://notfornoone.com/2010/07/install-php53-homebrew-snow-leopard/

brew install php --with-apache --with-mysql

I then went into my httpd.conf file:

```
cd /etc/apache2
sudo nano httpd.conf
```

And changed the line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so --> the old version
# Below is the link to the new homebrew version
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.7/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

(It depends where you install Homebrew, but the default is /usr/local)